# How to define custom code listing?

Tags: listings, code

I have the following custom listing but it throws error for `lstset` part that the keys are undefined. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{Sage}[]{Python}
{morekeywords={False,sage,True},sensitive=true}
\lstset{
  frame=none,
  showtabs=False,
  showspaces=False,
  showstringspaces=False,
  commentstyle={\ttfamily\color{dgreencolor}},
  keywordstyle={\ttfamily\color{dbluecolor}\bfseries},
  stringstyle={\ttfamily\color{dgraycolor}\bfseries},
  language=Sage,
  basicstyle={\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\ttfamily},
  aboveskip=0.3em,
  belowskip=0.1em,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize
}
\definecolor{dblackcolor}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{dbluecolor}{rgb}{0.01,0.02,0.7}
\definecolor{dgreencolor}{rgb}{0.2,0.4,0.0}
\definecolor{dgraycolor}{rgb}{0.30,0.3,0.30}
\newcommand{\dblue}{\color{dbluecolor}\bf}
\newcommand{\dred}{\color{dredcolor}\bf}
\newcommand{\dblack}{\color{dblackcolor}\bf}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

A code example:

\begin{lstlisting}
sage: R.<x> = ZZ[]
sage: type(R.an_element())
<type 'sage.rings...Polynomial_integer_dense_flint'>
sage: R.<x,y> = ZZ[]
sage: type(R.an_element())
<type 'sage.rings...MPolynomial_libsingular'>
sage: R = PolynomialRing(ZZ, 'x', implementation='NTL')
sage: type(R.an_element())  # this is a comment
<type 'sage.rings...Polynomial_integer_dense_ntl'>
sage: def abc():
...       """
...       This should be a very long comment.
...       That should span multiple lines.
...       To illustrate what colour Sage comments look like.
...       To get a feel for the color when rendered using LaTeX.
...       """
...       return 2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `\usepackage{xcolor}`

[Using colours in LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_colours_in_LaTeX)

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{Sage}[]{Python}
{morekeywords={False,sage,True},sensitive=true}
\lstset{
  frame=none,
  showtabs=False,
  showspaces=False,
  showstringspaces=False,
  commentstyle={\ttfamily\color{dgreencolor}},
  keywordstyle={\ttfamily\color{dbluecolor}\bfseries},
  stringstyle={\ttfamily\color{dgraycolor}\bfseries},
  language=Sage,
  basicstyle={\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\ttfamily},
  aboveskip=0.3em,
  belowskip=0.1em,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize
}
\definecolor{dblackcolor}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{dbluecolor}{rgb}{0.01,0.02,0.7}
\definecolor{dgreencolor}{rgb}{0.2,0.4,0.0}
\definecolor{dgraycolor}{rgb}{0.30,0.3,0.30}
\newcommand{\dblue}{\color{dbluecolor}\bf}
\newcommand{\dred}{\color{dredcolor}\bf}
\newcommand{\dblack}{\color{dblackcolor}\bf}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

A code example:

\begin{lstlisting}
sage: R.<x> = ZZ[]
sage: type(R.an_element())
<type 'sage.rings...Polynomial_integer_dense_flint'>
sage: R.<x,y> = ZZ[]
sage: type(R.an_element())
<type 'sage.rings...MPolynomial_libsingular'>
sage: R = PolynomialRing(ZZ, 'x', implementation='NTL')
sage: type(R.an_element())  # this is a comment
<type 'sage.rings...Polynomial_integer_dense_ntl'>
sage: def abc():
...       """
...       This should be a very long comment.
...       That should span multiple lines.
...       To illustrate what colour Sage comments look like.
...       To get a feel for the color when rendered using LaTeX.
...       """
...       return 2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I still get the same error in Overleaf. The problem is the keys inside `lstset` part.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If I copy and paste the "my code", I do not get any kind of error

Comment: @pixel Which error do you get with the code as it is in the answer? It seems to work find with up-to-date texlive.